# How to merge polygons from two different features without creating a hole in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, editing

How is it possible to merge the yellow polygon with the blue polygon without creating a hole and keeping the big yellow polygon intact. Each time I try to delete the small yellow polygon, the whole thing vanishes!

[image]

Comment: Small and big yellow polygons belong together because they are both parts of the same multipolygon. You must explode the multipolygon into separate polygons first. Then you can merge the small yellow with the blue one. Using the "split parts" option as in the answer by sunilk is one way to explode the multipolygon.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be possible by using Saga Union from QGIS processing tools. In following image I have a similar situation with two polygons.

[image]

Filtering the tool in the browser of processing, you will have the following dialog window after it is launched.

[image]

After click in Run, you will have a result similar to following image. I selected the small yellow polygon that you tried to delete. In this case, this is possible preserving the "big yellow" polygon intact (now it is brown).

[image]